# query SQL how to check all records from a three table join share the same value

Tags: sql

Since i'm a poor sql developer, i need support to write a sql query for the following scenario (just a simplified example of my situation):
i've got 3 tables, say employe table,department table and companybranch table.
the dept column , on the employe table is a fk on the department table; the branch column on the department table is a fk on the companybranch table.
Finally more employee are "marked" with the same value . 
There's a way to select all employes with the same "mark" and, in the same query, check that they work in the same company branch ?

thank you in advance

Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee e
JOIN department d ON e.dept = d.id
JOIN companybranch b ON d.branch = b.id
WHERE e.mark = 'mark here'
AND b.id = 'Branch id here'
```

**EDIT**

if you can't filter by branch, cause you don't know its value, then you can make a 
DISTINCT query, to check the differents b.id

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id branch_id
FROM employee e
JOIN department d ON e.dept = d.id
JOIN companybranch b ON d.branch = b.id
WHERE e.mark = 'mark here'
```

this is another option, you can check

```
SELECT inside.branch_id, COUNT(*) total
FROM (
    SELECT b.id branch_id
    FROM employee e
    JOIN department d ON e.dept = d.id
    JOIN companybranch b ON d.branch = b.id
    WHERE e.mark = 'mark here'
    ) inside
GROUP BY inside.branch_id
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but my problem is to find a way to verify all the records have a the same b.id indipendently by its value. In other words :
SELECT *  
FROM employee e 
JOIN department d ON e.dept = d.id 
JOIN companybranch b ON d.branch = b.id 
WHERE e.mark = 'mark here' 
having the same b.id 

i don't know if b.id is miami or los angeles i just want to be sure all records have the same b.id. Can i do such a thing in a single query or shall add a check with a programming language?

thanks again for your answer

Comment: But if you filter by b.id, aren't you ensuring they are all equal? see my updated answer

Comment: you are right, i can't filter the branch because i don't know its value. The rule is : "all the employee grouped by the same mark should be in the same branch". The example i've used migth be a bit confusing about why i don't use the branch to mark employees, but that just an example. Anyway the schema doesn't have any constraint about it , so i think i'll do as you suggest, i'll count the branches occurrencies and throw an exception if there are nultiple values.

Thank you again for your support